# Java Pattern Matching takes too much time to validate

Tags: java, regex, performance

I have a regular expression `([A-Za-z0-9 ]*){1,60}`.

I matched with the value `4503212220033000600034SS SS SS,ndklfjsldfld`...

After 20 seconds(approximately), it returns false because of `,` comma I used in my value.

Why it takes too much time to validate?

Comment: What do you want your  pattern to do? Now, it is matching **infinite** number of alphanumeric and spaces **1 to 60 times**. Did you mean `"[A-Za-z0-9 ]{1,60}"`?

Comment: [Catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) if used in the contect of `matches()`.

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern takes too much time due to [**catastrophical backtracking**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). Go to the *regex debugger* page at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pG3nG1/1) to see what is happening behind the scenes.

Now, your pattern matches infinite number of alphanumeric symbols and spaces 1 to 60 times, which is not logical if validation is meant.

If you need to match a string with 1 to 60 alphanumerical chars or spaces use

```
s.matches("[A-Za-z0-9 ]{1,60}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes regular expressions are a good idea.

But in your case, it seems like you are mainly interested in the stuff before and after the first space.

So, why do need a regular expression, if you could just call indexOf(' '); to find the position in your string that separates the important parts of your string?

I am not saying that using a regex is wrong (and probably, after fixing the "backtracking" issue it is what you need); but: too many people are using regular expressions merely because those exist ...

Comment: He's validating the string, so he's interested in all of it. Regex is definitely the best way to do this job.

Comment: Maybe. Or maybe not. He says he is "pattern matching takes too much time to validate. To me, it is not really clear what exactly he intends to do there.